# Error de instalación SDK en IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Buen día comunidad de StackOverflow!

Llevo días intentando instalar el ***SDK*** de Android a través de **IntelliJ IDEA**, en un principio pensé que el problema lo tenía por "lentitud" en mi conexión de internet pero ya me he dado cuenta que siempre se detiene en el mismo lugar (en la misma cantidad de megas).

A continuación muestro el error que me ha estado arrojando durante 4 días seguidos:

[image: problema intellij]

> Puede que el problema radique cuando descarga API 28 pero el detalle
>   es que el Intellij me "obliga" a descargar la última versión
>   disponible.

Existe alguna solución a este detalle? Hay alguna otra forma de descargar el ***SDK*** de Android para luego poder utilizarlo en **IntelliJ IDEA**?

Estoy atrasado 1 semana en el aprendizaje de Kotlin por este detalle, agradezco de antemando cualquier aporte.

Comment: Codigo 200 pero ocurrio un error al descargar esto puede ser obra de un proxy , revisa en el log que genera el IDE para saber el error especifico. Porque no usar el mismo android studio definiendo tus proyectos con soporte Kotlin.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, No tengo proxy es lo que me extraña. No uso el android studio, porque prácticamente noto que son iguales para descargar el SDK (no sé si esté equivocado). Es decir el android studio viene sin el SDK y cuando voy a descargarlo desde su interfaz es igual que con IntelliJ

Comment: @Jorgesys Sabrías donde ubico el log del IDE? Soy nuevo utilizando IntelliJ, de hecho descargué el community nada más para trabajar con Kotlin

Comment: ve  a Help - Show Log in Explorer/Finder

Comment: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml 
2018-06-10 15:13:41,356 [ 248627]   INFO - llij.help.impl.HelpManagerImpl - Failed to load help set from 'jar:file:///C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.4\help\ideahelp.jar!/idea/Help.hs' 
javax.help.HelpSetException: Could not parse
Got an IOException (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.4\help\ideahelp.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada))
Parsing failed for null

Comment: @Jorgesys esa parte es la que me muestra un fallo